# How can I auto_increment main and sub category conditionnaly?

Tags: mysql, index, auto-increment, condition

So I have a table of items as so

```
|mainCtgry |subCtgry|
---------------------
|     1    |   1    |
---------------------
|     1    |   2    |
---------------------
|     1    |   3    |
---------------------
|     2    |   1    |
---------------------
|     2    |   2    |
---------------------
|     3    |   1    |
---------------------
|     4    |   1    |
---------------------
```

So `mainCtgry` and `subCtgry` are the primary keys, you can't see it in the scheme but both are related to a string column let's say `mainStr` and `subStr`

My question is how can I auto-increment `subCtgry` based on the last `subCtgry` value related to `mainCtgry` (so `subStr`). Let be more clear if I enter for exemple `cat` into `mainStr` and `generic` into `subStr` then `mainCtgry` will be `1` and `subCtgry` will be `1`, now if I enter `cat` into `mainStr` and `Birman` into `subStr` I would like my `mainCtgry` to still be `1` and `subCtgry` to be `2`

Is this possible to automate this kind of behaviours in MYSQL?

Comment: Have look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52003972/how-to-create-table-in-sql-with-table-level-unique-key-with-table-level-identity#52004083 (Note: The question eventually turned out to be on SQL Server (not tagged properly before) but the answer I linked is for MySQL.)

Comment: thanks but as I don't really understand MYSQL propoerly I would prefer having an example just for my case just to be sure not to get lost with other examples. But thanks anyway I'll have a look and btw I'm not sure to be using the same engine as in the link you've sent me.

Comment: There is some discussion [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb#index_issue_2_column_pk)

Comment: @RickJames ok thanks I've changed the way of thinking for my DB but anyway thanks for the help